# What am I forgetting when trying to print these arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have two classes here, one that makes arrays, and one that should print them. When trying to compile the printing one, it can't identify the array-getting methods. What am I doing wrong? Here are the programs:

```
    public class IntegerArrayMain
{      
   private int[] numbers = new int [25];
   private int[] evens = new int [25];
   private int[] odds = new int [25];
   private int[] negatives = new int [25];
   private int sum;
   private int numbersSum;
   private int evenSum;
   private int oddSum;
   private int negaSum;
   private int avg;
   private int numbersAvg;
   private int evenAvg;
   private int oddAvg;
   private int negaAvg;

   DiceClass rng = new DiceClass(200);

   //============================NUMBERS====================================

   /**
   *Generates the 25 numbers.
   */
   public int[] setNumbers()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      {
         numbers[0] = (rng.getRoll() - 100);
         sum += numbers[i];
      }
      return numbers;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the numbers.
   */
   public int[] getNumbers()
   {
      return numbers;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the numbers.
   */
   public int setNumsSum()
   {
      int numbersSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         sum += numbers[i];
      }
      return numbersSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getNumsSum()
   {
      return numbersSum;
   } 
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the numbers.
   */
   public double setNumsAvg()
   {
       double numbersAvg = sum/numbers.length;
       return numbersAvg;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the numbers' average.
   */
   public int getNumsAvg()
   {
      return numbersAvg;
   }  
   //============================EVENS======================================

   /**
   *Locates the even numbers.
   */
   public void findEvens()
   {
      int n = 0;
      for(int i : numbers){
         if((i % 2) == 0){
         evens[n] = i;
         }
         n++;
      }
   }
   /**
   *Returns the even numbers.
   */
   public int[] getEvens()
   {
      return evens;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the evens.
   */
   public int setEvensSum()
   {
      int evenSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < evens.length; i++) {
         sum += evens[i];
      }
      return evenSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the even numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getEvensSum()
   {
      return evenSum;
   }  
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the evens.
   */
   public double setEvensAvg()
   {
       double evenAvg = sum/evens.length;
       return evenAvg;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the even numbers' average.
   */
   public int getEvensAvg()
   {
      return evenAvg;
   }  

   //============================ODDS=======================================

   /**
   *Locates the odd numbers.
   */
   public void findOdds()
   {
      int n = 0;
      for(int i : numbers){
         if((i % 1) == 0){
         odds[n] = i;
         }
         n++;
      }
   }
   /**
   *Returns the odd numbers.
   */
   public int[] getOdds()
   {
      return odds;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the odds.
   */
   public int setOddsSum()
   {
      int oddSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {
         sum += odds[i];
      }
      return oddSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the odd numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getOddsSum()
   {
      return oddSum;
   }  
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the odds.
   */
   public double setOddsAvg()
   {
       double oddAvg = sum/odds.length;
       return oddAvg;
   } 
   /**
   *Returns the odd numbers' average.
   */
   public int getOddsAvg()
   {
      return oddAvg;
   }  

   //============================NEGATIVES==================================

   /**
   *Locates the negative numbers.
   */
   public void findNegatives()
   {
      int n = 0;
      for(int i : numbers){
         if((i % 2) == 0){
         negatives[n] = i;
         }
         n++;
      }
   }
   /**
   *Returns the negative numbers.
   */
   public int[] getNegatives()
   {
      return negatives;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the negatives.
   */
   public int setNegativesSum()
   {
      int negaSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < negatives.length; i++) {
         sum += negatives[i];
      }
      return negaSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the negatives numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getNegativesSum()
   {
      return negaSum;
   }  
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the negatives.
   */
   public double setNegativesAvg()
   {
       double negaAvg = sum/negatives.length;
       return negaAvg;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the negative numbers' average.
   */
   public int getNegativesAvg()
   {
      return negaAvg;
   }  
}
```

And the other one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerArrayRunner
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      System.out.println("Numbers Array: " + getNumbers());
      System.out.println("Numbers Array Element Count: " + numbers.length());
      System.out.println("Numbers Array Sum: " + getNumsSum());
      System.out.println("Numbers Array Average: " + getNumsAvg());

      System.out.println("Evens Array: " + getEvens());
      System.out.println("Evens Array Element Count: " + evens.length());
      System.out.println("Evens Array Sum: " + getEvensSum());
      System.out.println("Evens Array Average: " + getEvensAvg());

      System.out.println("Odds Array: " + getOdds());
      System.out.println("Odds Array Element Count: " + odds.length());
      System.out.println("Odds Array Sum: " + getOddsSum());
      System.out.println("Odds Array Average: " + getOddsAvg());

      System.out.println("Negatives Array: " + getNegatives());
      System.out.println("Negatives Array Element Count: " + negatives.length());   
      System.out.println("Negatives Array Sum: " + getNegativesSum());
      System.out.println("Negatives Array Average: " + getNegativesAvg());

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the class and then use that reference to call the methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    IntegerArrayMain integerArrayMain = new IntegerArrayMain;

    integerArrayMain.callMethod1();
    integerArrayMain.callMethod2();
    //etc...
}
```

Alternatively you can make the methods and class variables static and then just call it by using ClassName.MethodName()